# Solving characteristic Differential Equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, characteristics

I have the following characteristic equation to solve:

$$
\frac{dt}{x^2} = \frac{dx}{-4xu} = \frac{du}{-4u^2}
$$

I start with:
\begin{align}
\frac{dt}{x^2} &= \frac{dx}{-4xu} \\
4udt &= -xdx \\
4ut & = \frac{-1}{2}x^2 + A
\end{align}

I then moved onto:

\begin{align}
\frac{dx}{-4xu} & = \frac{du}{-4u^2} \\
\frac{dx}{x} & = \frac{du}{u} \\
\ln u & = \ln x + \ln B \\
B & = \frac{u}{x}
\end{align}

I then said let $A = F(B)$ which then gives me:
$$
4ut + \frac{1}{2}x^2 = F(\frac{u}{x}) 
$$

However the solution given has:
$$
x + \frac{4tu}{x} = F(\frac{u}{x})
$$

what am I doing wrong?

thanks.

Comment: You should start with the last one  $$ \frac{dx}{xu} = \frac{du}{u^2} \implies x=c_1u$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the variables is constant along characteristics. Thus your first integration is wrong, $u$ is not constant. The second integration is correct.

If you insert $u=Bx$ into the first equation, you get $4Bdt=-dx$ so that $x=A-4Bt$.